# How to get value of text input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Inside Grid, there is a textbox with id 'txtRemarksByEntity' in column 'Approve/Reject', OnRowCommand, I need to retrieve the value of textbox.

```
function BtnProcurementApprovalByEntityClick(rowId, value) {
  var rowData = $('#GridProcureApprovalByEntity').getRowData(rowId);
  ReqIdApproval = rowData['RequestId'];
  ApprovalEntityId = rowData['approvalentityid'];
  ApprovalTypeId = rowData['approvaltypeid'];
  ApprovalStatusText = rowData['status_desc'];
  var ab = rowData["Approve/Reject"];
  var $str1 = $(ab);
  alert($str1.val());
}
```

In rowData variable, I am getting

```
Approval_Type:"Oprations"
Approve/Reject:"Remarks     <input type="text" id="txtRemarksByEntity"    class="txtRemarksByEntity" style="width: 250px">       <img src="images/yes1.PNG" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="BtnProcurementApprovalByEntityClick(5 , 1)">        <img src="images/cross1.PNG" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="BtnProcurementApprovalByEntityClick(5 , 2 )">"
RequestId:"51213"
Request_Id:"PR51213"
SrNo:"5"
approvalentityid:"2234"
approvaltypeid:"2"
status_desc:"<span style="color:#EAA66A"><b>Pending</b></span>"
statusid:"0"
undefined:"<button type="button" class="button edit" onclick="editProcureApprovalByEntity(5)">Edit</button>"
```

I am binding the grid dynamically as following

```
  $("#GridProcureApprovalByEntity").jqGrid({
    autowidth: true,
    height: 'auto',
    shrinkToFit: true,
    data: arr,
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['SrNo', 'PR No.', 'Approval Type', 'Approval Status', 'statusid', 'approvaltypeid', 'Approve/Reject', '', 'approvalentityid', 'RequestId'],
    colModel: [{
        name: 'SrNo',
        index: 'SrNo',
        width: 30,
        align: 'center'
    }, {
        name: 'Request_Id',
        index: 'Request_Id',
        width: 50,
        align: 'center'
    },
     {
         name: 'Approval_Type',
         index: 'Approval_Type',
         width: 100,
         align: 'center'
     }, {
         name: 'status_desc',
         index: 'Approval Status',
         width: 80,
         align: 'center',
         formatter: ApprovalFormatter
     }, {
         name: 'statusid',
         index: 'statusid',
         width: 0,
         hidden: true
     }, {
         name: 'approvaltypeid',
         index: 'approvaltypeid',
         width: 0,
         hidden: true
     },
    //{
    //            align:'center',
    //            formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
    //                return '<button type="button" class="button edit" onClick="editProcureApproval(' + options.rowId + ')">Edit</button>';
    //            }
    //        },

   {
       name: 'Approve/Reject',
       index: 'Approve/Reject',
       formatter: formateeApprovalByEntity, width: 250,
       align: 'center'
       },
  {
      formatter: formateApprovalByEntity, width: 50
  },
     {
         name: 'approvalentityid',
         index: 'approvalentityid',
         width: 0,
         hidden: true
     },
     {
         name: 'RequestId',
         index: 'RequestId',
         width: 0,
         hidden: true
     }

    ],
    pager: "#PagingGridProcureApprovalByEntity",
    rowNum: 10,
    //rowList: [1, 2, 3],
    //sortname: "Sno",
    //sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: true,
    hoverrows: false,
    gridComplete: function () {
        var recs = $("#GridProcureApprovalByEntity").getGridParam("reccount"); // parseInt($("#GridApproval").getGridParam("records"));
        if (isNaN(recs) || recs == 0) {
            $("#dvProcureAppGridByEntity").hide();
        }
    },
    ondblClickRow: function (rowId) {

    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#EEF7FB");
    }
    //,        caption: "Approval Details"
}).jqGrid("navGrid", "#PagingGridProcureApprovalByEntity", {
    search: false,
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    refreshstate: "current"
});



 function formateeApprovalByEntity(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
var str = '';
if (rowobject.statusid == "0") {
    str = 'Remarks     <input type="text" id="txtRemarksByEntity" class="txtRemarksByEntity" style= "width: 250px"/>' + '       ' +
        '<img src="images/yes1.PNG" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="BtnProcurementApprovalByEntityClick(' + options.rowId + ' , ' + 1 + ')"/>' + '        ' +
        '<img src="images/cross1.PNG" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="BtnProcurementApprovalByEntityClick(' + options.rowId + ' , ' + 2 + ' )"/>'
}
else {
    str = '';
}
return str;
}
```

$str1.val() is always ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of jqGrid contains many parts, which are incorrect, but the main reason of the problem which you asked is the usage of [custom formatters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) without specifying of the corresponding [unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting). You should define `unformat` callback, which **get** the data from the cell. If I correctly understand your code then you can use, for example,

```
unformat: function (cellvalue, options, cell) {
    return $(cell).find(".txtRemarksByEntity").val();
}
```

Some other errors:

- one should never assign `id` with the same static value to any elements inside of custom formatter. It produces **id duplicates**. You should remove `id="txtRemarksByEntity"` from `formateeApprovalByEntity` formatter, for example.
- the `name` value of every column of `colModel` should corresponds the requirements of `id` in HTML. It's bad to use special charachters inside of `name`. I'd recommend to change `name: 'Approve/Reject'` to `name: 'Approve_Reject'`, for example. In the same way the column `{ formatter: formateApprovalByEntity, width: 50 }` is wrong. It's the origin of `undefined` value of `rowData`. You have to specify some non-empty `name` value for the column, for example, `name: "approval"`.
- It's bad to specify `index` properties in `colModel` especially if you use `datatype: "local"`. The default value of `index` will be generated automatically by copying the value of `name` property. The value `index: 'Approval Status'` in the column `name: 'status_desc'` can prevent sorting and searching by the column. I'd recommend you to remove all `index` properties from `colModel`

Finally I'd ask you to specify the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), which you use, in *every question* about jqGrid. I develop free jqGrid fork, which I could recommend you to use. You can load it directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate and use data-attributes

```
if (rowobject.statusid == "0") {
    str = 'Remarks     <input type="text" id="txtRemarksByEntity" class="txtRemarksByEntity" style= "width: 250px"/>' + '       ' +
        '<img class="imgRemarksByEntity" src="images/yes1.PNG" style="cursor:pointer;" data-rowID="[' + options.rowId + ' , ' + 1 + ']"/>' + '        ' +
        '<img class="imgRemarksByEntity" src="images/cross1.PNG" style="cursor:pointer;" data-rowid="[' + options.rowId + ' , ' + 2 + ']"/>'
}
```

and have

```
$("#someStaticParentOfImage").on"click",".imgRemarksByEntity",function() {
  var rowId=$(this).data("rowid");
  BtnProcurementApprovalByEntityClick(rowId[0],rowId[1]);
});
```

Also IDs need to be unique

Comment: IDs are unique, and i am getting all column values accroding to RowID,but txtRemarksByEntity value is always blank.